# Hex codes for input key combinations

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, key-mapping

In `iTerm2` one can setup keyboard shortcuts so that for a given input sequence, iTerm2 sends a specific hex code to the terminal.

**What** exactly are these **hex codes**? And how can I identify a hex code for a given input key sequence?

In my case I am specifically interested in looking up the `hex code` associated with `Control + Alt + <char>` with char being `u`,`i`,`j`,`k` and `l`.

I found [this article](http://tangledhelix.com/blog/2012/04/28/iterm2-keymaps-for-tmux/) that shows some examples of these conversions, but it doesn't list any `Control + Alt + <char>` combinations.

The hope is that ultimately this will help me solve [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144481/sending-controlalt-char-to-terminal-in-iterm2) in AskDifferent.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a matter of *looking up* those keycodes, because in its default configuration iTerm2 doesn't do anything special for the keys.  For instance, if you do

```
cat -v
```

and press <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> ("literal next") before pressing each of those <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd>+*character* combinations, you're likely to find (as I did) that the result is just as if it ignored the <kbd>alt</kbd> modifier.  The rather long answer in *[Sending Control+Alt+ `<char>` to terminal in iTerm2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144481/sending-controlalt-char-to-terminal-in-iterm2)*  seems to have concluded something based on this default behavior which is not helpful.

On the other hand, you can *define* a key binding, using hexadecimal values for the (ASCII) characters that you would like to send.  In this screenshot, I have highlighted a binding that I added for <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> (lowercase `F`), which is `0x66`:

[image: example of send-hex-codes]

The [`iIterm2` documentation](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html) is brief:

> **Send Hex Code**
>
> This action allows you to enter a sequence of hex codes that will be sent. Each value should begin with **`"0x"`** followed by one or two hex digits (**`0-9`**, **`a-f`**, or **`A-F`**). Each code should be separated by a space. You can see a list of hex codes on http://asciitable.com/ in the **`"Hx"`** column.

but the screenshot here may help you understand what's needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a challenge to setup home and end. These are what I did.

Forward word - escape sequence f

Backward word - escape sequence b

Home - Hex code 1

End - Hex code 5

[image]